# Reverse proxy from apache server A to apache server B with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy

I am in the process of migrating a webapp from one server to another, and the IP address of the servers are different. I need to change the A record for the domain to the new server. To make sure the traffic to the old server lands up in the new server I need to setup reverse proxy in the old server which will redirect all traffic to new server.

I have several domains in the same server with different SSL certificates. The client will have a SSL connection the old apache server and the new server will accept connections through SSL only. So I need to setup reverse proxy with SSL connection. Is this possible in apache ? How do I achieve this? I am also worried about slowness due to two SSL connection setup times.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a migration, and not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible using mod_proxy and mod_ssl. See :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Remi, it is possible and to add, you do not have to worry about 2 SSL connections since I am assuming that the reverse proxy connection would have keep alive switched on and therefore the SSL connection setup between the two servers would only be carried out intermittently.

So remember to setup keep-alive. Any server worth its salt would support that and Apache does too.

Answer (score 0):

In the old server I would perform browser redirection "301  moved permanently" to the other IP/hostname (probably on the app root too, just to annoy them enough to change their bookmark and stop using ip addresses in favor of hostnames) . Light and effective.